# Getting contraint hibernate exception when POST/PUT/DELETE Method even with using cascade=CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, api, jpa

I'm trying to add a new Object to the h2-memory data base with POST Rest API.
I got this error : nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

In my Expense Entity I had put **@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)** so it's not supposed to create the category object before creating the expense object , isn't?

Thanks in advance.
Here is my entites:
public class Expense {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String description;
@Column(name = "expense_date")
private Instant expenseDate;
@Column(name = "location")
private String location;
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@Nullable
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Category category;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
@Nullable
@JsonIgnore
private User user;}
```

Category Class
public class Category {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
@NonNull
private String name;}
```

User Class:
public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String email;}
```

Comment: how u create ur tables?i think u have to nullable user_id and category_id

Comment: I create my tables with an sql file that I put in my classPath at first. After that I'm using spring data to CRUD

Comment: can u post that here?

Comment: insert into user(name,email) values ('Siamak', 'Codeengine11@gmail.com')
insert into user(name,email) values ('John', 'John@john.com')
insert into user(name,email) values ('Adam', 'adam@adam.com')
insert into category(name ) values ('Travel')
insert into category(name) values ('Auto Loan')

Comment: insert into category(name)  values ('Travel')
insert into expense(description,expense_date,location,category_id,user_id) values ('New York Business Trip','2019-06-16T17:00:00.000Z','Paris',1,1)
insert into expense(description,expense_date,location,category_id,user_id) values ('Ford Mustang Payment','2019-06-15T15:00:00.000Z','New York',2,2)
insert into expense(description,expense_date,location,category_id,user_id) values('Grand Canyon Trip With Family','2019-06-15T15:00:00.000Z','Los Angeles',3,1)

Comment: but i don't think that this data file has something to do with requesting the API . It's spring data that is responsible for that

Comment: ```insert into category(name ) values ('Travel')``` u did not fill id field

Comment: the id is auto generated mate

Comment: Problem solved when I deleted nullable=false in @JoinColumn .Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your definition of Expense class.
The annotation @Nullable - allows NULL values, and nullable = false - don`t allow.

Comment: i just commented that in the below comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when I removed nullable=false from @JoinColumn. because in Post method , I did not provide the id because it's generated so it's theorically nullable